# Salesforce Mobile SDK iOS - 'value' is unavailable: introduced in iOS 12.0

Tags: salesforcemobilesdk-ios

Using forcereact create and choosing the values:

`forcereact create --platform=ios --appname=MyReact -—packagename=com.mycompany.react --organization="Acme Software, Inc." -—outputdir=""`

When building and running in XCode I get the error:

`FBReactNativeSpec/FBReactNativeSpec.h:2220:88 'value' is unavailable: introduced in iOS 12.0`

What is the process to correct this?

Comment: This fix here worked for me - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72729591/fbreactnativespec-h-error-after-upgrading-from-0-68-x-to-0-69-0